# tag_list not showing up in form (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I've been working through this tutorial : http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html

got up to I3 - tagging

here is the error I am receiving:

```
undefined method `tag_list' for #<Article:0x007f87bceb23a0>
```

here is portion of my form that is causing the error:

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :tag_list %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</p>
```

here is my article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :tag_list, :image
  has_many :comments
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  has_attached_file :image

  def tag_list=(tags_string)
    self.taggings.destroy_all

    tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq

    tag_names.each do |tag_name|
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag_name)
      tagging = self.taggings.new
      tagging.tag_id = tag.id
    end
  end
end
```

my guess is that it does not like `def tag_list=(tags_string)`  but that is how it is written in the tutorial. If you need any more information let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the tutorial you use, `tag_list` is not a model field but a method that you should add to model:

```
def tag_list
  self.tags.map(&:name).join(', ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal : tag_list is not a column of your model, and `tag_list` method doesn't exist. You have to define

```
def tag_list
  self.taggings
end
```

Or

```
def tag_list
  self.taggings.map(&:name)
end
```

Or something like that.